# Plot latitude longitude from CSV in Python 3.6

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, folium

I'm trying to plot a large number of latitude longitude values from a `CSV` file on a map, having this format (first column and second column):

[image]

I'm using python 3.6 (apparently some libraries like `Basemap` doesn't operate on this version).

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking about a web-based map using google maps api? Or just a scatterplot with a map in the background?

Comment: I'm sorry...I mean on a real map!

Comment: This question has earned "popular question" badge, but I see a -2 vote!! Weird world.

Comment: Not really Python but check out [Kepler.gl](https://kepler.gl/demo)

Comment: @TinaJ - I would suggest the new OpenStreets answer to be the most current & correct answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you are just looking at plotting the point data as a scatterplot, is as simple as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x=df['Longitude'], y=df['Latitude'])
plt.show()
```

If you want to plot the points on the map, it's getting interesting because it depends more on how you plot your map.

A simple way is to use `shapely` and `geopandas`. The code below is not tested given my limited access on the laptop I am currently using, but it should give you a conceptual roadmap.

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame

df = pd.read_csv("Long_Lats.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=0, low_memory=False)

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude'])]
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)   

#this is a simple map that goes with geopandas
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(10, 6)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15);
```

Find below an example of the rendered image:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry...I mean a real map!

Comment: @TinaJ I apologize for misunderstanding. Has updated the answer. Cannot test if the code works on current laptop but would revise later if it does not.

Comment: @ Xiaoyu Lu, I have 3 type of class. So for every lattitiude and longitude there assign one class. How can I put 3 different color for 3 differnt class. i.e. class1 there is 60% geolocation, class2 20% and in class3 20% geolocation. here is my data structure, df['lattitiude','longitude','class'] = [53.679886 , 9.372680, 1]; class is labeled by 1,0,2

Comment: +1. Also, geopandas has a wrapper function: `points_from_xy()` which is equivalent to:
`[Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)]`

https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html?highlight=city

Comment: How can I zoom the `naturalearth_lowres` map into South Africa?

Comment: For people in future reading the answer, note the sequence: it is `Longitude` and then `Latitude`. Not vice versa.

Comment: @Superdooperhero do we have an answer yet about zooming in:?

Comment: @Sulphur I'm late over here but I think it is because of the convention of x being the first argument and y the second. Since, x depends on longitude, here longitude is the first argument. (x,y) -> (lon,lat)

Answer (score 26):

Here's an example of adding Lat & Long to a real OpenStreet map:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dataset/dataset.csv")

df.dropna(
    axis=0,
    how='any',
    thresh=None,
    subset=None,
    inplace=True
)

color_scale = [(0, 'orange'), (1,'red')]

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, 
                        lat="Lat", 
                        lon="Long", 
                        hover_name="Address", 
                        hover_data=["Address", "Listed"],
                        color="Listed",
                        color_continuous_scale=color_scale,
                        size="Listed",
                        zoom=8, 
                        height=800,
                        width=800)

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Example CSV:

```
Address,     Lat,       Long,      Listed
Address #1,  -33.941,   18.467,    1250000
Address #2,  -33.942,   18.468,    1900000
Address #3,  -33.941,   18.467,    1200000
Address #4,  -33.936,   18.467,    1195000
Address #5,  -33.944,   18.470,    2400000
```

Example output (interactive map):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add a scroll to navigate back and forth through time based series?

Comment: In this format: ```8.7,2015-03-09 15:56:39,34.642496,-92.890685,590
7.41,2015-03-09 15:56:39,34.642496,-92.890685,590
6.7,2015-03-09 15:56:39,34.642496,-92.890685,590
7.41,2015-03-09 15:56:39,34.642496,-92.890685,590
10.1,2015-03-09 15:56:39,34.642496,-92.890685,590
6.6,2015-03-09 15:56:39,34.642496,-92.890685,590
10.3,2015-03-09 15:56:39,34.642496,-92.890685,590
6.7,2015-03-09 15:56:39,34.642496,-92.890685,590```

Answer (score 18):

You can also use plotly express to plot the interactive worldmap for latitude and longitude

[image: DataFrame Head]

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("location_coordinate.csv")

fig = px.scatter_geo(df,lat='lat',lon='long', hover_name="id")
fig.update_layout(title = 'World map', title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

Comment: No need to put the dataframe head as a link/image. You can simply format it as code and put it inline with your answer.

Comment: Sure Noted Thank you.

Comment: It tells me that I havent installed nbformat, even though I had. Doesnt work