# How to use latitude/longitude data from excel to graph a map on python?

Tags: python, excel, maps

I have a list of facility buildings and their respective latitude and longitude points, and I want to create a map marking their locations. How do I go about doing so? Any tutorial resources would be helpful as I am new to python.

Comment: Your question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233228/plot-latitude-longitude-from-csv-in-python-3-6 . You can get some ideas from there. There are many other questions about how to read a excel file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.